# Compilation errors for PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST(
 inv_number IN NUMBER,
 cust_id IN NUMBER,
 date_in IN DATE,
 date_out IN DATE,
 Sub_tot IN NUMBER,
 tax IN NUMBER,
 total IN NUMBER) 
IS
 in_date DATE;
 out_date DATE;
BEGIN
 in_date = to_date('date_in','MM/DD/YY');
 out_date = to_date('date_out','MM/DD/YY');

 IF ( out_date-in_date <= 3 AND out_date-in_date >= 0 ) THEN
 INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES( inv_number, cust_id, date_in,date_out,
                              Sub_tot,tax,total);
 ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( "Date_in and Date_out wrong");
COMMIT;
END TEST;
/

ERROR: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

The problem is at the In_date and Out_date right? but i don't know how to solve it. 
what is the errors that inside my code?

Comment: When you get that 'with compilation errors' message, you should do `show errors` or query the `user_errors` view to see the actual problems in the stored PL/SQL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't get to_date from date field `'in_date = to_date('date_in','MM/DD/YY');'`
date_in already is date field.
to_date changes string to date format, to_char changes date to string here you dont need that
and  '=' -  compare, ':=' - conferment

working code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST(
 inv_number IN NUMBER,
 cust_id IN NUMBER,
 date_in IN DATE,
 date_out IN DATE,
 Sub_tot IN NUMBER,
 tax IN NUMBER,
 total IN NUMBER) 
IS
 in_date DATE;
 out_date DATE;
BEGIN
 in_date := date_in;
 out_date := date_out;

     IF ( out_date-in_date <= 3 AND out_date-in_date >= 0 ) THEN
    -- INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES( inv_number, cust_id, date_in,date_out,
    --                              Sub_tot,tax,total);
    dbms_output.put_line('true');

     ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Date_in='||to_char(date_in,'MM/DD/YY')|| ' and Date_out='||to_char(date_out,'MM/DD/YY')||' wrong');
    --COMMIT;
    END IF;
END TEST;
/

begin

 TEST(inv_number =>1,
          cust_id =>1,
 date_in =>sysdate,
 date_out =>sysdate+6,
 Sub_tot=>1,
 tax =>1,
 total=>1); 

 end;
```

Comment: it's always display PL/SQL succesfully completed. but doesn't show the output out. what should i do ?

Answer (score 3):

This code, unfortunately, doesn't make a lot of sense.

You're passing in two `date` parameters, `date_in` and `date_out`.  Since you're passing in `date` values, it makes no sense to call `to_date` on them-- `to_date` does not accept a `date` parameter.

If you want to reference a variable in your PL/SQL, you'd reference the variable.  You appear to be using hard-coded string values that happen to be the string name of your procedure's parameter.

It doesn't make sense to declare local variables `in_date` and `out_date` which just replicate the data in your input parameters.  Just reference the input parameters in your code.

You're missing the `END IF` in your `IF` statement.

Plus, it's generally a bad idea to embed `commit` statements in procedures since that makes them non-reusable.  And it's good practice to actually list the columns you want to `insert` values into in your `insert` statement both because that makes your code more clear and it makes it easier to support.  I also missed the fact that you were using double-quotes to delimit your string rather than single quotes.

My guess is that you want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ...
IS
BEGIN
  IF ( date_out-date_in between 0 and 3 ) 
  THEN
    INSERT INTO INVOICE (<<list your columns>> )
      VALUES( inv_number, cust_id, date_in,date_out,
              Sub_tot,tax,total);
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Date_in and Date_out wrong');
  END IF;
END TEST;
```

Comment: it's work but doesn't store the data into my tables.
always pl/sql completed. and although i put an invalid value for date_in date_out, it should go to the else statement, but still dispaly pl/sql procedure completed

Comment: @user3553846 - You should never rely on a human seeing anything written to `dbms_output`.  Are you sure that your client has enabled `dbms_output` and that it is configured to read and display the results?  If you're using SQL*Plus, you'd need to `set serveroutput on` before calling the procedure in order to see the output.  Other tools will have other configuration steps that need to be made.